What do "Protected Web API" refer in Microsoft Graph SSO Authentication Flow
We are building a web-based, JavaScript Outlook Add-In which is required to call Microsoft Graph APIs to access the Outlook's user's emails and attachments.
The authentication process is being implemented using Single Sign-On (SSO) as outlined in the Microsoft documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph
snapshot1
For the server-side code of the Office Add-In in the snapshot above, I am referring to the documentation on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/web-apps-apis/on-behalf-of-flow, and I need some clarification regarding the phrase "calls a protected web API."
snapshot2
What exactly does "protected web API" mean in this context?
I referred to the Microsoft documentation and tried the following:

Configured the Azure AD application for the add-in with appropriate permissions, including Mail.Read and Mail.ReadWrite for Microsoft Graph.
Used the Office.context.auth.getAccessToken API to obtain an authentication token in the add-in client.
Set up server-side code which takes token A and return token B, which eventually send to client side to call Microsoft Graph.

Need clarification on what Microsoft wanted to state "protected web API" in documentation linktext for server-side code.
